# how to configure SQL Server max memory usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. SQL Server 2008 always tries to eat as much as memory as it could. Any ways to configure per database or per instance or per server level max memory usage of SQL Server 2008?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the max usage for a SQL instance in Management Studio by right-clicking on the relevant instance in Object Explorer, choosing properties, then Memory, and choosing your maximum, as detailed here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144.aspx

However, it's generally not necessary to do this unless your other apps or instances are actually having problems getting memory. Simply seeing that the server appears to have no free RAM is not a problem in itself, but normal behaviour.

Comment: +1, and I'd like to add that SQL should be running on its own box. It is designed to use as much memory as it can to make things faster.